# How to update the total amount when tip is selected

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple food delivery service. I'm trying to figure out how to update total amount when tip is selected

```
    if(choiceRegular.checked == true) {
        var totalPrice = choiceRegular.value;
    }else if (choicePremium.checked == true) {
        totalPrice = choicePremium.value;
    }else if(choiceRoyal.checked == true) {
        totalPrice = choiceRoyal.value;
    }else {
        totalPrice = 0;
    }


    if(tenTip.checked == true) {
        var tipPrice = tenTip.value * totalPriceNum
    } else if(fiveTip.checked == true) {
        tipPrice = fiveTip.value
    } else if(twentyTip.checked == true) {
        tipPrice = twentyTip.value
    } else {
        tipPrice = 0
    }



    totalPriceNum = Number(totalPrice);
    tipPriceNum = Number(tipPrice);



    document.getElementById('total-amount').innerHTML = '$'+totalPriceNum;
```

Comment: Just call the code using checkbox onclick event.

Comment: Alex, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include all the necessary HTML for someone to reproduce your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<input id="tenTip" class="tipSelector" name="tip" data-tip-value="10" type="radio" />
<input id="fiveTip" class="tipSelector" name="tip" data-tip-value="5" type="radio" />
<input id="twentyTip" class="tipSelector" name="tip" data-tip-value="20" type="radio" />
```

JS

```
const totalAmount = document.getElementById('total-amount');
document.querySelectorAll('.tipSelector').forEach(tipSelector => {
  tipSelector.onclick = () => {
    totalAmount.innerHTML = totalPriceNum * (1 + tipSelector.dataset.tipValue / 100);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding the full scope I think in your case `totalPriceNum = Number(totalPrice) + Number(tipPrice);` would be the combined total.

If values for `totalPrice` and `tipPrice` have already been declared you might want to make it a function in `JS`

as a function e.g.:

```
    function refreshTotal(){
      var totalNumBeforeTip = Number(totalPrice);

      if(tenTip.checked == true) {
        var tipPrice = tenTip.value * totalPriceNum
      } else if(fiveTip.checked == true) {
        var tipPrice = fiveTip.value
      } else if(twentyTip.checked == true) {
        var tipPrice = twentyTip.value
      } else {
        var tipPrice = 0;
      }
      var tipPriceNum = Number(tipPrice);
      var combinedTotal = totalNumBeforeTip + tipPrice;
      var priceResultElement = document.getElementById('total-amount');
      priceResultElement.innerHTML = '$'+combinedTotal;
    }
```

in the html something like:

```
    add $5 tip <input type="checkbox" id="tip-5" value="5.00" onChange="refreshTotal()">
```

Comment: The total price has to be calculated and tip add to it on click

Comment: make it a function for example `function refreshTotal() { //here sum values and report new total back }` Then you can have an `eventListener` for `onChange` or an `onClick` in the HTML object that calls this `refreshTotal` function.